# java adding data to a JTable with a for-loop

Tags: java

i need some help writing a for-loop please but i can't get it.

i need to add the numbers 0 to 63 in a table like this:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
etc.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {  
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
     table.setValueAt(""+(i+(j)), i, j);
 }
}
```

but the inputted values are not correct
can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you're trying to do this so you count left to right top to bottom and have 8 columns)

You need to offset the value each time for the number of columns you've seen.  Every time you iterate through an entire row, you've seen 8 columns, so it's not sufficient to add `i` and `j`, you need to add rows seen (`i`) multiplied by the number of columns (8).  Thus you should be printing `i*8 + j`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
        table.setValueAt(""+(i*8+j), i, j);
    }
}
```